# Filling a date between a data range in array?

Tags: javascript

I have to arrays of dates like this:
[6/13/2011, 7/15/2011, 7/18/2011, 8/13/2011] 
what i want to do is to fill the date between the date array so if theres days missing between any of the date like  7/15/2011, 7/18/2011 i want to add 7/16/2011, 7/17/2011 between them, is there a way or a lib can help do this ?

Comment: Is it Java or JavaScript? You've tagged the question with both, but their respective date objects are quite different.

Comment: Just a simple for loop would do the job.  Your use case is far too narrow for there to likely be a library tailored directly to it.

Comment: @Barend Garvelink actually i dont mind if it was in Java or JavaScript, any one of these will be fine to me.

Comment: @mellamokb  the problem is you have to take in the account the month days in the year and if there is something available out there it will be faster for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work in JavaScript.  It basically just dismisses any dates in the middle of the array, and generates all dates in between the first and last items.

```
var dates = ["6/13/2011", "7/15/2011", "7/18/2011", "8/13/2011"];

var minDate = new Date(dates[0]).getTime(),
    maxDate = new Date(dates[dates.length - 1]).getTime();

var newDates = [],
    currentDate = minDate,
    d;

while (currentDate <= maxDate) {
    d = new Date(currentDate);
    newDates.push((d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
    currentDate += (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // add one day
}

console.log(newDates);
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! just replace currentDate = min, with currentDate = minDate,

Comment: Good catch with the min/minDate typo. I tried to clean up the variable names and missed that. Thanks for the accept!